# In what way I can automate my home?

Tags: automation

I need to connect all of the systems in my home and make them responsive to me at any time from any location. I tried to search in google but information what I found was incomprehensible for me.

Comment: You are talking about IOT concept.. search IOT (Internet of things) you will get something ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about [Home Automation](http://tibbo.com/programmable.html)? you can simply connect all of the systems in your home and turn them into a "smart home". The automation is, actually, the combining of two or more of systems which are known as subsystems.